# Override and overwrite method in the same class

Tags: c#

Look at the following non-compiling C# code:

```
public abstract class Operation
{
    public abstract void Work();
}

public abstract class Operation<T> : Operation
{
    public override void Work()
    {
        Work();
    }

    public new abstract T Work();
}
```

While it's possible to introduce a new name overwriting one in a base class, it doesn't seem to be possible to still override the previous method in the base class - in order to do the override, one would have to define a conflicting method.

Is there something I overlooked or is this impossible to do?

Comment: Methods could not differ by return type

Comment: When you have a compiler error, try reading it. If you don't understand it, ask a question about it but please do include the error message.

Comment: Try putting base.Work() in the new Work method. It should be "new virtual", not abstract

Comment: @Frode 1) No implementation is provided, so yes, it most certainly should be `abstract`.  `abstract` also implies `virtual`.  2) The new work method *has* no implementation, and so has no place to call the base method 3) That would in no way fix the fact that he has two members with the same name, which is why his code (even with your fixes) doesn't compile.

Comment: @vmeln They can in the case of explicit interface implementations. There just are no equivalent explicit overrides, which was the question I was asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option, as much as you may not like to hear it, is that you could simply come up with a new method name, rather than shadowing the other method:

However, another more radical change would be for `Operation` to be an interface, rather than an abstract class with no implementation.

```
public interface IOperation
{
    void Work();
}
```

At this point you can also make the inheriting type an interface as well, since it doesn't need an implementation:

```
public interface IOperationWithResult<T> : IOperation
{
    T Work();
}
```

Or you could make it an abstract class that simply implements the interface explicitly:

```
public abstract class Operation<T> : IOperation
{
    public new abstract T Work();

    void IOperation.Work()
    {
        Work();
    }
}
```

Personally I'd go with two interfaces and no abstract classes here, given that these types aren't conceptually providing any real implementation, nor are they conceptually abstract types.  Their purpose is to define a contract that many otherwise unrelated types could meet (namely the ability to do some work or compute some result) which is precisely what interfaces are for.

Comment: Using differently named methods is what I usually do, and yes, making one an interface can also work. I just thought there might be a better way.

Comment: @John There is a better way.  Use two interfaces.  As I said, that's the best solution here.  There really isn't any reason to have *any* abstract classes.  As general advice, I'd suggest that you be wary of using abstract classes in general.  I find that they're very rarely the appropriate tool for most tasks.  (This generally comes down to the old saying "favor composition over inheritance.")